# Spring create unique @Component for every POST request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Say I have a Spring validator that is annotated with `@Component`. This validator runs every time a POST request comes in. It is `@Autowired` in to the controller.

Problem here is that the validator is a singleton by default. It also contains a list storing any and all errors. Everytime this validator is called, the list is emptied.

My worry is that if multiple requests come in at the same time, this validator would break.

Is there anyway to still utilize the power of Spring Boot but make sure that everytime the `@PostMapping` is called, the instance gets a new fresh validator only for itself?

Comment: "My worry is that if multiple requests come in at the same time, this validator would break." So ensure that it's thread-safe and it won't matter

Comment: Can you show your validator?

Comment: @Michael Would making this shared list or map in this case a type of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap solve the issue? Issue is that I don't want any thread to share the data of the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
@Component
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
```

to ensure that for each Request an own component is created.

Or

```
@RequestScope
@Component
```